# chrome extension which will read text inside the particular TAG?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, tags

I am trying to create chrome extension which will read text inside the particular TAG from the Webpage ...
but not able to read value
I need to pick Text inside the tag definition excluding html tags..
here i want to read the value from the tag "definition"

**output**:is an overwhelming urge to have  of something  is often connected with money
suppose web page is like this

```
<div id="definition">
<div class="section blurb">
<p class="short"><i>Greed</i> is an overwhelming urge to have <i>more</i>
 of something
<p class="long"><i>Greed</i> is often connected with money</p>      
</div>  
</div>
```

this is what i was trying
popup.html

```
<script>
  var newwin = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
      newwin.get(); 
</script>
```

background.html

```
 <Script>

    function get()
    {
    var myDivObj = document.getElementById("definition");
    if ( myDivObj ) {
       alert (myDivObj.innerHTML); 
    }else{
       alert ( "Alien Found" );
    }
    }

    </Script>
```

Comment: Hint: [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: What @RobW said.

Put all but the <script> tags in the content script...

Comment: It Worked .!!! t4NQ ..Rob and Chirs ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my script from the background page to content scrit and it worked like charm..

but was just wondering why dint work in background page..?